# Animate path between 2 points which always change in: SVG React native, animated3

Tags: react-native, svg, path, react-native-reanimated

Got 2 pixel points on a svg map, I can easily dray a line or path between those 2 points. I want to animated the draw of the path over 2 seconds.

Here's my code

```
const [pointAPixels, setPointAPixels] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
const [pointBPixels, setPointBPixels] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);
const animationProgress = useSharedValue(0);

useEffect(() => {
animationProgress.value = 0;
            animationProgress.value = withTiming(1, {
                duration: 1500,
                easing: Easing.linear,
                // useNativeDriver: false, // Enlevez cette ligne si elle n'est pas nécessaire
            });
}, [pointAGPS, pointBGPS]);

const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
        const length = interpolate(animationProgress.value, [0, 1], [100, 0]);

        console.log(length, animationProgress.value);
        return {
strokeDasharray: "10",
            strokeDashoffset: length,
};
    });

return (
<View>
<SvgFrance width={320} height={320} fill={black} />
<AnimatedPath
                        d={`M ${pointAPixels.x} ${pointAPixels.y} L ${pointBPixels.x} ${pointBPixels.y}`}
                        // d={pathData}
                        stroke="black"
                        strokeWidth="2"

                        // strokeOpacity={animationProgress}
                        // strokeDasharray="5" // Configurer ici la valeur de strokeDasharray
                        animatedProps={animatedProps}

                    />
</Svg>
</View>
);
}
```

I've pasted the most important code.

I played a lot with

```
        strokeDasharray: "10",
        strokeDashoffset: length,
```

But I can't figure out the length of path because it's always changing...

Comment: Maybe you can try with https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/core/useAnimatedProps/

Comment: Adding a  [`pathLength` ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) attribute to your paths might solve the problem as you can define a fixed length value for all dasharray calculations.

Comment: @Martinocom isn't it what I'm already doing ?

Comment: @herrstrietzel after reading that doc, I can see
_<!-- No pathLength, the real length of the path is used. In that case, 100 user units -->_
Then it's better to not provide pathLength ?!

Comment: @yannou974: that's the point defiine `pathLength="100"` and `stroke-dasharray="100 100"` will fill up the complete path length no matter how long the path actually is.

Comment: @herrstrietzel that's also working great, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
        const x = interpolate(animationProgress.value, [0, 1], [pointAPixels.x, pointBPixels.x]);
        const y = interpolate(animationProgress.value, [0, 1], [pointAPixels.y, pointBPixels.y]);
        // console.log(x, y, animationProgress.value);
        return {
            d: `M ${pointAPixels.x} ${pointAPixels.y} L ${x} ${y}`,
        };
    });
```